# ordering text variable in sql in ascending order, where first the Latin letters , then the Cyrillic letters

Tags: sql, sorting, ssms

How can i  sort the data in the order that I need, taking into account that I sort inside the group by `customer`
I.E.

```
select
customer
, sku
, stuff
, action
, acnumber
, year
from mytable
```

first I sort by SKU ascending from lowest to highest, 
then acnumber ascending from lowest to highest,
 then year from lowest to highest, then for each group scu + acnumber + year I have to sort the Customer variable, where the first, the Latin letters increase in ascending order, and then the Cyrillic symbols

an example of how this should look like I gave

for example, for 2017 year, and for acnumber number 2 and 13-sku, Customer must be ordered in this way

```
Z
А
Б
В
```

how to sort it?
now I have a Cyrillic symbols at first

```
А
Б
В
Z
```

taking into account the fact that this must be done for each group
scu +  acnumber + year

i.e  it is necessary that the order was like this

```
    Customer SKU stuff action acnumber year
1        z  12    20     30        1 2017
2        z  13    20     30        1 2017
3        А  13    20     30        1 2017
4        Б  14    20     30        1 2017
5        Z  13    20     30        2 2017
6        А  13    20     30        2 2017
7        Б  13    20     30        2 2017
8        В  13    20     30        2 2017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
order by acnumber,
         (case when customer like '[a-zA-Z]%' then 1 else 2 end),
         customer
```